# How can I pass jQuery $(this) to a jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, this, scope

We're all familiar with the trick of saving the `$(this)` selector as a variable and passing it to another function like so:

```
var storedthis = $(this);

function dosomething(storedthis) {

// I can use storedthis in the scope of this function no problem now...

}
```

But what if I've initialized a dialog on document `.ready()` and I want to preserve `$(this)` when I open the jQuery `.dialog()` box from an event handler, for example `.on()` the `foucusout` of an `input` tag?

How can I pass that in to be usable in the `.dialog()`?

There are some SO explaining how to use `.data()` but I don't think that will work because I'm not setting a value to anything and my understanding is that jQuery stores things like `$(this)` as objects.

Comment: This is an interesting concept but I am having some difficulty following the flow. If I understand correctly then you would like to preserve the `$(this)` as it refers to the button that initiated the `dialog()`? Where within the `dialog()` code would you like to use `$(this)` to reference the button?

Comment: Could you post some mock-up code and put a comment as to where you want to reference the `$(this)` please? Or even post a link to an SO question that didn't suit your needs.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: In this case the modal dialog is being called from `focusout` on an `input` box so I want to preserve `$(this)` scope to put some data in that original input box once the user has selected it from the modal.

Comment: I think you have a bit of confusion about javascript variable scope. You don't need to add it as parameter of a function. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Um2ZX/

Comment: @ProGM: You do when you have dynamically generated content. Anyway that's off topic. I'm asking about something else.

Comment: Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/JLWUq/2/